# Ionic6 with Xcode gives " Thread 1: signal SIGABRT " with any iPhone using <=ios12

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using ionic capacitor to make my application, The application works normally under android and ios13+ , but with iPhone 6 or older (any iPhone using iOS12) it gives the error below

[image]

Comment: What’s your capacitor version? Capacitor 4 doesn’t support iOS 12

Comment: Capacitor :  "@capacitor/core": "3.6.0"

Comment: @capacitor/device": "^4.0.1"

Comment: I've downgraded the version of @capacitor/device to 1.1.2 , and the error disappeared, but the application stuck on wight screen , may be  another issue

Comment: And the @capacitor/ios version?

Comment: @capacitor/ios": "3.6.0"